# C++. Функция LoadString

Tags: c++, winapi

Согласно спецификации функция LoadString принимает среди параметров уникальный целочисленный идентификатор строки. Что это такое? Каким значением я должен его задавать?

Comment: Таким же самым как в файле ресурсов привязаных к hInstance.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Спасибо!